# How to make filter and search work together?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component:

```
export default class Shop extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    search: "",
    filters: [],
    items: json
  };


  onFilterChange = ( event ) => {
    const checkboxes = [...event.currentTarget.closest(".filter").getElementsByTagName("input")]
    const filters = [];
    checkboxes.map(checkbox => {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        filters.push(checkbox.name);
      }
    });
    this.setState({ filters }, this.filtredInput);
  }


  filtredInput() {
    let items = json

    if (this.state.filters.length !== 0) {
      items = items.filter(element => this.state.filters.every(key => element[key]));
    }


    if (this.state.search.length !== 0) {
      items = items.filter(word =>
        word.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
      )
    }

    this.setState( {items} )
  }

  onSearchChange = ( {currentTarget} ) => {
    const search = currentTarget.value
    this.setState({ search }, this.filtredInput() )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="navigation">
          <Filter
            onFilterChange={this.onFilterChange}
          />
          <Search
            onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
          />
        </div>
        <Filtered
              items={this.state.items}
              updateShoppingBasket={this.updateShoppingBasket}
            />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Help to organize the logic so that both the search and the filter work simultaneously. Individually, everything works fine. But in the current version, the search works as if with a delay (apparently, the code works before the state is set), but I'm not sure that there are no other errors. How to organize the logic of the filter + search correctly in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this much easier on yourself by thinking about the data differently. If you have it as a requirement that you always store the latest filtered data, then this won't work. I have included a custom code example here (including components that the example depends on): https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cohen-sg263?file=/src/App.js

I like to think about the three pieces of data that we need to store to perform our operation.

1. The search term
2. The list of filters
3. The list of items we want to filter and search within

We can download the list of items from an API if we need to, and this way we can ensure we never lose data by filtering and replacing.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  /*
    there are three things we store

    1. the current search term
    2. the current list of filters
    3. the entire list of data we want to search and filter through
       (this can start as an empty array and then be filled with data from an API)
  */
  state = {
    term: "",
    filters: [],
    list: [
      {
        color: "red",
        name: "car"
      },
      {
        color: "blue",
        name: "plane"
      },
      {
        color: "red",
        name: "boat"
      }
    ]
  };

  /* This handles toggling filters, when the filter is clicked it will check
     the array and add it if it isn't there.
  */
  toggleFilter = filter => {
    if (this.state.filters.includes(filter)) {
      this.setState({
        filters: this.state.filters.filter(item => item !== filter)
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        filters: [...this.state.filters, filter]
      });
    }
  };

  updateTerm = term => {
    this.setState({
      term
    });
  };

  /* selector function to filter a list of items */
  applyFilters = list => {
    if (this.state.filters.length === 0) {
      return list;
    }

    return list.filter(item => this.state.filters.includes(item.color));
  };

  /* search function to filter for the search term */
  applySearch = list => {
    if (this.state.term === "") {
      return list;
    }

    return list.filter(item => item.name.startsWith(this.state.term));
  };

  render() {
    /* we can filter the list and then search through the filtered list */
    const filteredItems = this.applyFilters(this.state.list);
    const searchedItems = this.applySearch(filteredItems);

    /* we pass the filtered items to the list component */
    return (
      <>
        <Filters onChange={this.toggleFilter} />
        <Search term={this.state.term} onChange={this.updateTerm} />
        <List items={searchedItems} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps build a different mental model for React. I intentionally avoided making the Filters a controlled component, but only to show you the filter in the render function. Always open to discussion. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank. I analyzed your example :)